# Collect and flatten in Activerecord association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I need to add a post's author ID to comments on a post for one reason or another. I wanted to have an activerecord query like this:

```
User.includes(posts: :comments).where('whatever').each do |user|     
  user.posts.collect{|post| post.comments}.flatten.update_all(post_author_id: user.id)
end
```

The collect/flatten combination unfortunately leaves me with an array rather than an activerecord association, so update_all doesn't work.

I could obviously do rewrite the query from the other direction, but I was basically just curious if there's a way similar to collect/flatten to arrive at an association of this sort of indirectly associated objects. That is, without adding the `:through` association in my model.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why you would want to do this - perhaps there is a better way to design it so that this wouldn't be necessary?

Anyhow, there is one way to turn an array into an AR relation though, I guess one thing you could do is take the output array that you have generated with your method and do this:

`Model.find your_array.map(&:id)`

Unfortunately, that would cause AR to do another query, but the result that you get is indeed an AR relation back.

Comment: Yeah, I know it can be done easily with another query; the situation is modeled after one I am dealing with, but I was mostly just curious. 

I think the question boils down to whether there's an easy way to query as if you had already defined a `:through` relationship.